# Chamada de função Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um carrinho de compras, estou querendo colocar um elemento dentro de uma DIV, este elemento tem uma função Jquery que não está funcionando sua chamada(função de remover produtos do carrinho).

```
$('.add_produto').click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           url: CI_ROOT + "frontend/site/add_produto",
           data: {
              id:$(this).attr("idproduto"),
          },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            var verifica = $('.recebe_produto #'+data.produto.id_produto+'').html();

            $('.carrinho_vazio').remove();
            if (verifica == undefined) {

                var html =  '<div class="produtos_carrinho" id="'+data.produto.id_produto+'">'
                        +'<div class="imagem_carrinho"><img src="'+CI_ROOT+'img/'+data.produto.foto+'" style="margin-top:5px;"></div>'
                        +'<div class="carrinho_excluir">'
                            +'<a href="#" title="Alterar quantidade"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>'
                            +'<a style="cursor:pointer;" class="remove_produto" idproduto='+data.produto.id_produto+' qnt='+data.id_qnt+' title="Remover produto"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>'
                        +'</div>'
                        +'<div class="descricao_carrinho">'
                           +' <font color="#A02D34">'+data.produto.nome+'</font><br>'
                            +' <span class="qnt">'+data.id_qnt+'</span> un - R$ <span class="valor">'+data.valor+'</span>'
                        +'</div>'
                        +'</div>'
                        $('.recebe_produto').append(html);
                        remove_produto();                        

            }else{

                $('#'+data.produto.id_produto+' .qnt').html(data.id_qnt);
                $('#'+data.produto.id_produto+' .valor').html(data.valor);
                $('#'+data.produto.id_produto+' .remove_produto').replaceWith('<a style="cursor:pointer;" class="remove_produto" idproduto='+data.produto.id_produto+' qnt='+data.id_qnt+' title="Remover produto"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>');

            }
            var verifica_valor = $('.recebe_valor').html();

                        if (verifica_valor == "") {
                            var valor = '<div class="valor_carrinho">'
                            +'<div class="preco_carrinho">'
                                +'R$ <span class="total_produtos">'+data.valor_total+'</span><br>'
                                +'R$ 5,00<br>'
                                +'R$ <span class="total_carrinho">'+data.valor_total+'</span>'
                            +'</div>'
                                +'Total produtos <br>'
                                +'Taxa entrega <br>'
                                +'<b>TOTAL GERAL</b>'

                        +'</div>';
                        $('.recebe_valor').append(valor);

                    }else{

                        $('<span class="total_produtos">'+data.valor_total+'</span>').replaceAll('.total_produtos');
                        $('<span class="total_carrinho">'+data.valor_total+'</span>').replaceAll('.total_carrinho');   
                    }
        }   
    });
});
function remove_produto(){
     $('.remove_produto').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("idproduto");
        var qnt = $(this).attr("qnt");
        $.ajax({
            url: CI_ROOT + "frontend/site/remover_produto",
            data: {
                id:id,
                qnt:qnt,
            },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){

                if (data.id_qnt >= '1') {

                    $('#'+id+' .qnt').html(data.id_qnt);
                    $('#'+id+' .valor').html(data.valor_parcial);
                    $('.carrinhovazio').remove();
                    $('#'+id+' .remove_produto').replaceWith('<a style="cursor:pointer;" class="remove_produto" idproduto='+id+' qnt='+data.id_qnt+' title="Remover produto"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>');
                    remove_produto();
                }else{

                    $('#'+id).remove();

                }

                if (data.valor === 0) {

                    $('.valor_carrinho').remove();
                    var html = '<div class="carrinho_vazio">'
                        +'<div class="carrinhovazio"><img src="'+CI_ROOT+'img/carrinho.jpg" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:50px; width:50%;"></div>'
                        +'</div>'
                        $('.recebe_produto').append(html);

                }else{  

                    $('<span class="total_produtos">'+data.valor+'</span>').replaceAll('.total_produtos');
                    $('<span class="total_carrinho">'+data.valor+'</span>').replaceAll('.total_carrinho');

                }        
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Favor editar sua pergunta postando mais detalhes, de preferência incluindo o trecho de código relevante para que possamos avaliá-lo. Na forma como está, não está claro o que está perguntando.

Comment: cara posta o codigo ai

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem da função de adicionar produtos no carrinho, preciso chamar a função remove_produtos, más atualmente do jeito que está não funcionada a chamada.

Comment: Na verdade ela chega a funcionar más não corretamente, quando clico em excluir produto, ele está fazendo várias requisições envés de apenas uma

Comment: A função remove_produtos.                                  function remove_produto(){
         $('.remove_produto').click(function(){

Comment: @Fortunato Está impossível de ler... há alguma razão para não se postar o texto do código, em vez de uma imagem do mesmo?

Comment: Sim, o código está meio grande e não sei a razão quando tento colar o mesmo ele não aparece. Não sei se tenho que usar alguma tag para postar o código. Primeira vez usando aqui.

Comment: @Fortunato 1. cole o código; 2. selecione-o inteiro; 3. clique no botão "amostra de código" na barra de edição (se parece com isto: **{ }**)

Comment: www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Pronto está todo ai o código agora, o que está acontecendo é que ele faz mais de uma requisição quando deveria fazer apenas uma, e as vezes não funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu problema me parece ser que você está adicionando o *handler* à classe `remove_produto` várias vezes (uma vez a cada chamada de Ajax). Além disso, quando seu código entra no primeiro `else` você está substituindo elementos dessa classe por outros (`replaceWith`), e em nenhum momento você adiciona um *handler* a eles.

A maneira mais simples que vejo para solucionar isso é usar [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) na classe `remove_produto`. Substitua a função `remove_produto` por:

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_produto", function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("idproduto");
    var qnt = $(this).attr("qnt");
    ...
});
```

O método `on` tratará do evento `click` para todo elemento com a clase `remove_produto`, **atual ou futuro**, de modo que você não precisa reatribuí-lo cada vez que fizer Ajax. Ou seja, execute o código acima **apenas uma vez**.

Comment: Muito obrigado mgibsonbr funcionou perfeitamente agora. Realmente o problema era este.